# Bootstrap JQuery Validate: error message between input and <span class="add-on">

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

When using Twitter Bootstrap and Jquery Validate in a combination everything goes right except when using a field with an (icon) add-on like:

```
<label>Datum:</label>
<div id="datum" class="input-append">
   <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" type="text" name="datum" placeholder="Kies een datum..." />
   <span class="add-on">
      <i data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

When there is an error the HTML looks like this:

```
<label>Datum:</label>
<div id="datum" class="input-append">
   <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" type="text" name="datum" placeholder="Kies een datum..." />
   <label for="datum" generated="true" class="error" style="">Datum is verplicht.</label>
   <span class="add-on">
      <i data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

And this is how it looks in the browser:

[image: Browser example]

How to fix this?
Hope someone can help!

**EDIT**

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        { onkeyup: false
            //form validation rules


            // LOGIN FORM
            $("#loginform").validate({        
                onkeyup: false,
                 rules: {
                    gebruikersnaam: {
                        required: true           
                    },
                    wachtwoord: {
                        onkeyup: false,
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    gebruikersnaam: {
                        required: "Vul aub een gebruikersnaam in."                      
                    },
                    wachtwoord: {
                        required: "Vul aub een wachtwoord in.",
                        minlength: "Wachtwoord moet minimaal 5 tekens langs zijn.",
                    },
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });

            // NIEUWE DISTRIBUTIE OPDRACHT


    $("#distributieopdracht").validate({  

        onkeyup: false,
         rules: {
            opdrachtgever: {
                required: false                
            },
            datum: {
                required: true
            },
            frequentie: {
                required: true
            },
            actie: {
                required: true
            },
            product: {
                required: false
            },
            aantal: {
                required: false,
                digits: true
            },
            koeling: {
                required: true
            },
            tarief: {
                required: false,
                decimal: true
            },
            naam: {
                required: false,
                naam: true
            },
            adres: {
                required: false
            },
            plaats: {
                required: false
            },
            telefoonnnummer: {
                required: false,
                telefoon: true
            },
            opmerkingen: {
                required: false
            },
        },
        messages: {
            datum: {
                required: "Datum is verplicht."
            },
            frequentie: {
                required: "Frequentie is verplicht."
            },
            actie: {
                required: "Keuze is verplicht."
            },
            aantal: {
                digits: "Alleen getallen."
            },
            koeling: {
                required: "Keuze is verplicht."
            },
            tarief: {
                decimal: "Vul een geldig tarief in."
            },
            naam: {
                naam: "Vul een geldige naam in."
            },
            telefoonnnummer: {
                telefoon: "Vul een geldig telefoonnummer in."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $("#loginform").validate({        
        onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
               gebruikersnaam: {
                   required: true           
               },
               wachtwoord: {
                onkeyup: false,
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 5,
               }
           },
           messages: {
               gebruikersnaam: {
                required: "Vul aub een gebruikersnaam in."                      
               },
               wachtwoord: {
                   required: "Vul aub een wachtwoord in.",
                   minlength: "Wachtwoord moet minimaal 5 tekens langs zijn.",
               },
           },

       });


      $("#distributieopdracht").validate({  
            onkeyup: false,
             rules: {
                opdrachtgever: {
                    required: false                
                },
                datum: {
                    required: true
                },
                frequentie: {
                    required: true
                },
                actie: {
                    required: true
                },
                product: {
                    required: false
                },
                aantal: {
                    required: false,
                    digits: true
                },
                koeling: {
                    required: true
                },
                tarief: {
                    required: false,
                    decimal: true
                },
                naam: {
                    required: false,
                    naam: true
                },
                adres: {
                    required: false
                },
                plaats: {
                    required: false
                },
                telefoonnnummer: {
                    required: false,
                    telefoon: true
                },
                opmerkingen: {
                    required: false
                },
            },
            messages: {
                datum: {
                    required: "Datum is verplicht."
                },
                frequentie: {
                    required: "Frequentie is verplicht."
                },
                actie: {
                    required: "Keuze is verplicht."
                },
                aantal: {
                    digits: "Alleen getallen."
                },
                koeling: {
                    required: "Keuze is verplicht."
                },
                tarief: {
                    decimal: "Vul een geldig tarief in."
                },
                naam: {
                    naam: "Vul een geldige naam in."
                },
                telefoonnnummer: {
                    telefoon: "Vul een geldig telefoonnummer in."
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.next().is('.add-on')) {
                    error.addClass('add-on').insertAfter(element.next('.add-on'));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
                error.append(element.parent());
           });
    });

});
```

**FORM**

```
<div id="distributie" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="distributieLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="modal-form" action="submit.php" data-remote="true" method="post" id="distributieopdracht">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="distributieLabel">Nieuwe Distributie Opdracht</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <label>Opdrachtgever:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="opdrachtgever" placeholder="Typ hier de opdrachtgever..." /><br /> 

            <label>Datum:</label>
                <div id="datum" class="input-append">
                    <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" type="text" name="datum" placeholder="Kies een datum..." />
                    <span class="add-on"><i data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>

            <label>Frequentie:</label> 
                <select name="frequentie">
                    <option value="">Kies een frequentie...</option>
                    <option value="eenmalig">Eenmalig</option>
                    <option value="dagelijks">Dagelijks</option>
                    <option value="wekelijks">Wekelijks</option>
                    <option value="tweewekelijks">Twee-wekelijks</option>
                    <option value="maandelijks">Maandelijks</option>
                    <option value="jaarlijks">Jaarlijks</option>
                </select><br /> 

            <label>Actie:</label>
                <select name="actie">
                    <option value="">Kies een actie...</option>
                    <option value="ophalen">Ophalen</option>
                    <option value="afleveren">Afleveren</option>
                </select><br /> 

            <label>Product:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Typ hier een product..." /><br /> 

            <label>Aantal colli:</label>
                <input type="text" name="aantal" placeholder="Typ hier het aantal..." /><br />

            <label>Koeling:</label> 
                <select name="koeling">
                    <option value="">Kies een optie...</option>
                    <option value="ja">Ja</option>
                    <option value="nee">Nee</option>
                    </select><br />

            <label>Tarief:</label>
                <input type="text" name="tarief" placeholder="Typ hier een tarief..." /><br />

            <label>Naam:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="Typ hier een naam..." /><br /> 

            <label>Adres:</label>
                <input type="text" name="adres" placeholder="Typ hier het adres..." /><br />

            <label>Plaats:</label>
                <input type="text" name="plaats" placeholder="Typ hier de plaats..." /><br />

            <label>Telefoonnummer:</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" placeholder="Typ hier het telefoonnummer..." /><br />

            <label>Opmerkingen:</label>
                <textarea rows="3" name="opmerkingen" placeholder="Typ hier eventuele opmerkingen..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Invoeren" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

**Current situation:**

[image: example 2]

**Goal:**

[image: example 2]

**EDIT**

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.next().is('.add-on')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.next('.add-on'));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
                element.parent().insertAfter(error);
            }
```

**Working solution by @jani-hyytiainen:**

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        if (element.next().is('.add-on')) {
             error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } 
        else {
             error.insertAfter(element);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show your bootstrap and jQuery code.

Comment: Which part of the bootstrap and jquery code do you exactly need? @bpeterson76

Comment: If you have a problem with how your jQuery is working, then **show your jQuery**.

Comment: You're showing us the rendered code, which is essentially worthless.  Validate is add the class="error" code, which we can understand from your screenshot.  To fix it, we have to get to the root of why the code is firing incorrectly.  That happens with the jQuery code, which we can't see.

Comment: No the validating works fine, only when there's a span element right after an input element the error message is shown between the input and the span element.. @Sparky

Comment: That would have been an important detail to add.....

Comment: Yes of course.  The Validate plugin is inserting it there by default.  There is no HTML-only solution, thus the reason we're all asking to see your jQuery code.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry ;) But can I post the whole validate plugin here? Or do you just need a certain part of it?

Comment: We don't need to see any part of the plugin(s).  We're talking about any JavaScript or jQuery that _you_ wrote... your `.validate()` function?  How else would you have defined your rules and/or options?

Comment: One thing I noticed right away:  You can remove the entire `submitHandler` option, since `form.submit()` is the default behavior of the plugin anyway.  (nothing to do with your issue.)

Comment: @Sparky I've edited my question again. Because I tried to remove that submitHandler option. When I did that, the validation didn't work anymore. So this is the whole file.

Comment: You do not need all that extraneous `JQUERY4U.UTIL` junk. Just put your `.validate()` function(s) inside of a `document.ready` function. Study the code of this generic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R7MSq ~ My demo only uses a `submitHandler` to bypass any real submission since it's inside of a jsFiddle. I don't know how you removed your `submithandler` function, but maybe you did not remove the whole thing? See how I commented out mine here: http://jsfiddle.net/R7MSq/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the errorPlacement option in here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.parent().append(error);
    }
});
```

You can also test if there is an add-on present, change the placement of the error message, style it similarly to add on and so forth:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.next().is('.add-on')) {
            error.addClass('add-on').insertAfter(element.next('.add-on'));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

It would look like this:

[image: Error Placement with add-on class]

Sorry, no icon for the calendar but it's the square after the input.

Comment: that should be **appendTo** - element.parent() will be the surrounding div, appendTo will place the error inside that div at the end.

Comment: This is useful but my 'Datum' field is combined with that span element and that two elements are together in a div. The rest of the input fields are not in a div and end like </input><br />. @jani-hyytiainen

Comment: @politus, actually I was looking for element.parent().append(error); I have fixed it in my reply and added more details too.

Comment: Hmm where do I have to implement that? Between $("#distributieopdracht").validate({  
   **and**    onkeyup: false, ? And if possible, I would like to keep my own layout.

Comment: @user2131419, organize it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/R7MSq/3 ~ The listing order of the plugin options does not matter.

Comment: @Sparky I've edited my question again and added an updated version of my jquery code. But the code isn't working with errorPlacement part from Jani. Without it works fine. I can't see what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: @user2131419, You are also doing both error.insertAfter(element); and error.append(element.parent()); this adds 2 error messages, I suppose you want to remove the latter one.

Comment: Jani:  Both versions of your `errorPlacement` callback function are missing the closing brace, `}`.  When you properly indent the code within the callback function, the error is obvious.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/R7MSq/8/

Comment: @user2131419, that's because there is a syntax error in Jani's code. The closing brace, `}`, for the `errorPlacement` callback function is missing.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/R7MSq/8 You can also use the jsHint button in jsFiddle to find any syntax errors.

Comment: @Sparky so it seems. It is fixed now.

Comment: Don't forget about your first version too.

Comment: @Sparky, Ahh that's why the error slipped... I did that one in the bus with mobile on my way home from work. Then later copied over the error on the second example :) Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I've changed my code like you guys said and now it looks like the newly added image. So it's almost fixed..! But is it possible to remove that gray background behind 'Datum is verplicht' and that it looks like the other validation errors @Sparky

Comment: Just remove the .addClass('add-on'), I only provided it as an example as I just found out that you can have multiple .add-on one after another and bootstrap will style them together. This was new for me so I thought I'd share. But you can remove it and the error message will style normally.

Comment: Just did that and it looks much better now. The only thing is that the 'Datum' input is within a div (and the other input fields are not) and the error will also be inserted in that div as you can see in the code in my question. I would like to float the error messages right. As shown in the last image (Goal) of my question. So the line '<label for="datum" generated="true" class="error" style="">Datum is verplicht.</label>' has to be inserted after the div.. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put that piece of code? Or instead of which part?

Comment: I've edit my post. It doesn't work like this.. I'm sorry but I'm an absolutely noob at javascript..

Comment: Try this errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.next().is('.add-on')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for your patience and help Jani & @Sparky! I've also learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with **Date picker validation** in **bootstrap 3**.
To fix this, I checked if the element is date picker then display error outside the element's parent group, else perform the default action.

Here is the Final code.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
    if ($(element).hasClass("date-picker") ) {
        error.insertAfter($(element).closest('.input-group'));
    }
    else
    {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
};
```

Hope this will help someone :)